# Does unsubscribing from a Workshop item delete the mod files?

Tags: steam-workshop

After "unsubscribing" (mods are installed by "subscribing") from a Steam Workshop item there are a dozen respective files all around the game installation location and the mod is still active in the game. Is unsubscribing supposed to delete the mod files or do I have to manage local Workshop content manually?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/5zwtn1/psa_when_unsubscribing_from_workshop_maps_they/) (and my own experience removing mods), the files are not actually removed. They still exist in the games folder. You have to go in and manually remove them yourself.

For example, they would be still located here:

> File Location: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo\maps
>
> Also here: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Counter-Strike Global
>   Offensive\csgo\maps\workshop

Unsubscribing will stop updates from occurring.

Comment: Left 4 Dead 2 currently deletes unsubscribed Workshop mods (`~\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Left 4 Dead 2\left4dead2\addons\workshop`), appears to be done on game launch. Because L4D2 is a Valve game Workshop functionality may have been updated.